# How i can hide a Progressbar()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

That's the code on how you can hide a Progressbar() on tkinter.

```
bar = Progressbar(window, length=200, mode="indeterminate")
bar.grid(row=3, column=1)
bar.start(10)
bar.grid_forget() # To hide or remove the progressbar by TheLizzard
```

Comment: If you used `.grid`, use `.grid_forget` to hide the widget. Also first you are using `bar.grid(..)` then you are using `bar.pack(...)`. That's bad practise.

Comment: Ty so much, it works with bar.grid_forget(), im a beginner on python GUI (tkinter). Thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so : you don't have to place your bar at first ,which mean you don't have to use `bar.grid(row=3, column=1)` .But, when you need you bar to appear then use it . for example :

```
def show_bar():
    bar.grid(row=3, column=1)
btn = Button(text = 'show progress bar',command = show_bar)
```